# Large blue arc from capacitor when shorting it - how deadly was this situation and how much energy was inside?

Tags: voltage, transient

I was working on a transient circuit and I applied a 8kV, 2 ohm voltage transient on its input with a rise time of 10us and fall time of 50-100uS. It comes from a transient generator off mains so can provide an excess of 5kA if required.

(Stupidly) I was touching the circuit, and decided to do another test and everything seemed okay. I for some reason thought this time I better just check these caps are discharged and got an insulated test lead and shorted the capacitor out. It flashed this massive blue arc and made a loud bang as it did. Obviously, it made me realize how lucky I am and im still a bit sketched working with the circuit now.

I wanted to get some details from the community about how close to death I really was there, how much energy predictably would of been in the capacitors and energy it would of taken to be deadly?

I will provide some circuit details below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frkSlF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The transformer's secondary was shorted. It has 1 ratio of 1:1 and has 750u. It presents 0.2 ohms of impedance and has an inductance of 750uF. The capacitors are low ESR surge capacitors rated a 500+ volts. I dont know their ESR but its in the region of 1-2 ohm.

Comment: You're working with a circuit involving 8kV and poking it with your fingers? Lucky is an understatement.

Comment: I would strongly suggest to stop what you are doing immediately.

Comment: Honestly, something like that you may even have mild flash burns that you haven't noticed yet. This is a massively unsafe thing to be doing and you really ought to stop, double check your safety protocols, and have a second person in the room with you when you do anything with this stuff.

Comment: In addition to the deservedly dire comments you're getting, applying 8kV with those 500V caps seems pretty iffy, too. You're relying on R2 to keep the two caps' legs (on the high-voltage side) within ~1000V of each other, but 1) is it small enough resistance? and 2) What kind of resonances are happening with the C1-Lxfrm-C2 circuit?

Comment: @bitsmack Im hoping the fuse blows before things get too haywire. I consistently see the circuit draw 1kA+ which blows the fuse pretty quick to the point where I saw a 30KA fuse, violently explode. The transformer does ring when the fuse goes for 20-50uS reaching a couple kV. Its somewhat hard to predict exaclty at what point of current and voltage the fuse will blow as strangley datasheets dont have much of a rating up this end on a 500mA fuse.

Comment: Yeah, strange indeed :-)  Seriously, if you're blowing fuses you're doing it wrong. Please don't rely on them. It sounds like you should start modelling the circuits beforehand to see what to expect, start following high-voltage ("arc-flash") safety procedures (including getting safety equipment), and (perhaps) find a mentor.

Comment: 20ma through the chest can reliably kill just about anyone, but some might die from only 10ma, if it hit right at the right time, like a baseball to the chest. If the current wasn't going from one arm to the other you would _likely_ just get burned and shocked. not saying its a good idea, just trying to answer your question about "how close".

Comment: To add, find the energy curve with 0.5*C*V^2 and then integral or average it to get the total energy. Simulation software may have work here instead of risking your life.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> how much energy predictably would of been in the capacitors

Assuming the capacitors divide the voltage and each is charged to 4 kV, the energy would be about 1 joule each. How much damage that would cause depends on how small and sensitive an area absorbed the energy. A baseball pitched by a professional would have well over 100 joules of energy and is routinely stopped safely by a glove, but could cause serious brain damaged if it is stopped by someone's forehead. A 22 caliber bullet has about the same energy, but would concentrate its energy in a much smaller area. A 1 joule arc would cause a nasty burn on a person's hand, but it would probably heal without causing any permanent disability. If someone managed to discharge a 4 kV, 1 joule charge with both hands it could kill them, but more likely wouldn't.

Comment: 1+ for baseball to head analogy